# Broadcast receiver being discarded

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have the following code in my android manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.DDD.CCC.BBB.AAA" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

On the first boot, sometimes the android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED is not received but sometimes it does.

The event log, when the broadcast is received shows that:

```
01-16 05:34:01.649  1230  1274 I am_proc_start: [0,3811,1000,com.DDD.CCC,content provider,com.DDD.CCC/.databases.XXX]
01-16 05:34:01.659  1230  2798 I am_proc_bound: [0,3811,com.DDD.CCC]
01-16 05:34:05.389  1230  1561 I am_kill : [0,3811,com.DDD.CCC,15,empty #14]
01-16 05:34:05.389  1230  1242 I am_proc_died: [0,3811,com.DDD.CCC]
01-16 05:34:11.899  1230  3470 I am_proc_start: [0,4642,1000,com.DDD.CCC,broadcast,com.DDD.CCC/.service.AAA]
01-16 05:34:11.929  1230  1561 I am_proc_bound: [0,4642,com.DDD.CCC]
01-16 05:34:16.579  1230  1242 I am_kill : [0,4642,com.DDD.CCC,15,empty #14]
01-16 05:34:16.609  1230  1568 I am_proc_died: [0,4642,com.DDD.CCC]
01-16 05:34:16.859  1230  1568 I am_proc_start: [0,5079,1000,com.DDD.CCC,broadcast,com.DDD.CCC/.service.AAA]
01-16 05:34:16.889  1230  1274 I am_proc_bound: [0,5079,com.DDD.CCC]
01-16 05:34:16.979  1230  2641 I notification_enqueue: [com.DDD.CCC,262082,NULL,0,Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.DDD.CCC/0x1090064 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 kind=[null])]
01-16 05:34:19.559  1230  2798 I am_kill : [0,5079,com.DDD.CCC,15,empty #14]
01-16 05:34:19.559  1230  2642 I am_proc_died: [0,5079,com.DDD.CCC]
```

when it does not receive, it shows the following:

```
01-16 05:41:29.809  1232  1506 I am_proc_start: [0,3793,1000,com.DDD.CCC,content provider,com.DDD.CCC/.databases.AAA]
01-16 05:41:29.809  1232  2338 I am_proc_bound: [0,3793,com.DDD.CCC]
01-16 05:41:36.939  1232  3326 I am_kill : [0,3793,com.DDD.CCC,15,empty #14]
01-16 05:41:36.949  1232  3325 I am_proc_died: [0,3793,com.DDD.CCC]
01-16 05:41:37.879  1232  1269 I am_proc_start: [0,4337,1000,com.DDD.CCC,broadcast,com.DDD.CCC/.service.AAA]
01-16 05:41:37.899  1232  2339 I am_proc_bound: [0,4337,com.DDD.CCC]
01-16 05:41:41.359  1232  1244 I am_kill : [0,4337,com.DDD.CCC,15,empty #14]
01-16 05:41:41.369  1232  2355 I am_proc_died: [0,4337,com.DDD.CCC]
01-16 05:41:41.369  1232  2355 I am_broadcast_discard_app: [0,1109557712,android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED,21,ResolveInfo{428381d0 com.DDD.CCC/.service.AAA m=0x108000}]
```

Yes, i've seen that the process is dead and it is not restarted again.
Does anyone has any clues of why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: Please post the code from `onReceive()`. If you are doing too much work in this method, Android will just kill your process and move on to the next one. You can't do anythging that takes any significant time in `onReceive()`.

Comment: Yeah, but this means that at least the onReceive would be reached and killed right?
So what happens is that, the boot completed broadcast is logged, but the next one (sim state changed) does not reach the onReceive.
So by what we know, if the receiver was doing too much work, it would kill and move to the next one (so if it was the first broadcast, the second one would be called, and if it was the second one, a third one would be called)
But the problem is that the second onReceive, sometimes it is not called at all.
Is it possible that the process is killed while both broadcast are received?

Comment: Something like, the second broadcast is queued, while the first broadcast (boot completed) is being processed. After the first broadcast is finished, the process is killed, and the second broadcast is ignored. Is it possible this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

After receiving a first or second broadcast If you onReceive process takes longer, the broadcast will be the third generation ANR has confirmed that am_broadcast_discard_app occurred.